# JQuery each method doesn't set "this" parameter correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

The code below outputs

```
#document
#document
```

My expectation is that it outputs

```
#document
#head
```

Why is this not the case?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $("head").each((index, element) => {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

jQuery's own docs state:

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword **this** refers to the element. (https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Possibly I'm missing some subtlety about the `.call` method (which is how jQuery invoked the anonymous function in the `.each` call) or closures. However, my understanding is that `.call` can be used to set the `this` parameter.

Comment: You're using an arrow function which [doesn't have it's own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but uses the one from its outer lexical environment. That's why both outputs are `document`.

Comment: Was in the middle of typing the same as above. Here's a fiddle proving the point: https://jsfiddle.net/6x2uewrq/

Comment: Nice. Figured there'd be a simple answer. Thanks for the fast response. If you provide as an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: And if I'd gone and looked at the arrow function docs then it's all there :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions